# Updating large number of records without an index on a nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to relatively quickly update a large number of records in SQL Server 2014, filtering on a `nvarchar(x)` column, when there is no index on this column?

Eg. I'd like to run:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET Active = 1 
WHERE ProductBrand = 'brand name'
```

on my `Product` table with millions of rows, and there is no index on `ProductBrand`.

Creation of the index takes around 45 minutes and we would like to update the table a bit faster.

We want to perform this operation fastest way possible, creating index takes lots of time. I was wandering if there are some other ways than using the index.

(Creating an index on the name column and leaving it there is of course a good practice, as well as rebuilding it from time to time)

Comment: You create the index only once, then you can use it for all updates later... 45 minutes doesn't seem like that much time for a one time operation...

Comment: If you have Enterprise edition, index creation can be done without interrupting other transactions by using the `WITH ONLINE = ON` option. Also, if `brand name` is a specific, unique value and the index on `ProductBrand` will never be needed again (which, frankly, seems unlikely) you can explicitly filter the index with `WHERE`. This will not speed up index creation, but it will reduce the storage requirements. You *will* need an index to speed things up, though, because *fast filtering is exactly the problem indexes are designed to solve*.

Comment: If you don't want to create the index, then just run the update statement without it. It will still work, and it will likely take less than 45 minutes (though possibly not *much* less, depending on your load). But if there was any way of speeding it up without using an index, SQL Server would already be doing it.

Comment: If you do not have an index on ProductBrand it is going to scan the entire table no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your product table, maybe you have an index on ProductBrandId, if not, you can create a new tmpProduct table with same structure and default 1 in "Active" field.

Insert all registers into the new table

Drop the original table and rename then tmpProduct to Product

You must ensure that all triggers and references are recreated

Comment: The suggestion to look for a possibly indexed field is a good one, but there is no way that creating a brand new table is a faster alternative to doing an `UPDATE` or creating an index. Aside from being far more complicated and posing problems with concurrently happening transactions, it will take far more I/O than either.